# Laravel Chatter library does not wokr when I dont serve the application and directly use localhost/chatter/forums

Tags: laravel-5

I installed devdojo/chatter. Installation is fine but the /forums route does not work when i use my application directly like localhost/chatter/forums. When I serve the same application it works. Is there any way we can use this without serving.

I tried serving the application by command php artisan serve. and I get the proper page.

below is the image showing errors while using the library without serving the app.

[image]

Comment: Was your application running fine before the installation of Chatter?

Comment: Yes. and still working fine. its just that /forums does not work.

Comment: I see the package has not been updated for over a year. I suggest you start looking for other packages which have more recent updates. This indicates the Chatter package is abandoned and probably not updated to work with the latest versions of Laravel.